# *ngIf not working if expression contains a string

Tags: angular, input, angular-ng-if

I have a todo component with read, edit and insert modes. The template looks something like this:

```
<form *ngIf="editMode=='edit' || editMode=='insert'" class="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]='todoForm' novalidate>
  .... edit and insert mode contents
</form>

<span style="line-height: 33px;" *ngIf="editMode=='read'">
  .... read mode contents

</span>
```

The todo component contains these two input variables:

```
  @Input() todo: Todo;
  @Input() editMode: string;
```

And I have a list component that has a list of todo components like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class='todos-container'>
    <ul class="list-group">

      <li *ngFor="let todo of todos" class="list-group-item clearfix">
        <todo-component [todo]='todo' [editMode]='read'></todo-component>
      </li>
      <li class="list-group-item clearfix">
        <todo-component [todo]='newTodo' [editMode]='insert'></todo-component>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that neither the form nor the span are visible. When editMode is a simple boolean then it works correctly. `*ngIf="editMode"` or `*ngIf="!editMode"` works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try === instead of == in your condition

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work

Comment: EditMode is an input property you need to provide quotes while supplying value like this [editMode]="'read'"

Comment: Without quotes its trying to look up variable named read from outer component which does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
[editMode]="'read'"
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#template-expressions

or

```
editMode="read"
```

for example

```
<todo-component [todo]='todo' editMode="read"></todo-component>
```

then `editMode` will be string `read`

See also

- https://vsavkin.com/angular-2-template-syntax-5f2ee9f13c6a

Comment: Yes, this works! Thanks Both of these solutions work. Now that I think about it seems logical that I somehow need to convert the value in the attribute to a string. But it does look a bit weird, especially the first syntax

Comment: It looks like it was designed :) First syntax is a template expression `[property]="expression"`

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind:

[directive]= “string”
directive = “valueOfAVariable”